# Does porn in Esperanto exist?

Tags: culture

I was having a conversation with a friend of mine. Just curious if the rule 34 applies.

I can't search for it on the internet because of too many false positives.

Comment: It doesn't follow from rule 34 that porn **in** Esperanto exists, only that porn **"of"** (read: "about", _pri_) Esperanto exists.

Answer (score 8):

There's the [Libro de Amo](http://egalite.hu/kalocsay/sekretaj.htm). The UEA has [this description](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?inf=3310) of it:

> Enhavas la faman amoran poemciklon "Sekretaj sonetoj" (1931) kaj diversajn similtemajn poemojn, originalajn kaj tradukitajn.

For example, this is Sonnet XLII of the *Sonetoj Sub Sep Sigeloj*.

> ```
> En lit' vi bubviziton ne permesis,
> rezigne flustris: "La monata sang'".
> Sed malkvietis spite mia Stang',
> vi ĝin karesis mole. Sed ne ĉesis
>
>
> la ŝvelo, kompreneble, eĉ, impresis
> jam obeliske. Nun kun brula vang',
> vi proksimiĝis al ĝi kaj per lang'
> kaj per la lipoj vi ĝin ekkaresis.
>
>
> Kaj — nun eksuĉis vi entuziasme.
> Ho, dolĉturmenta vibro en la nuk'!
> Volupto torda, morda! Dum orgasme
>
>
> en vian buŝon ŝprucis arda suk':
> barakte, ĝeme, senkonscie, spasme
> mi mordis vin je l' alabastra pug'!
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Just started reading "Ĉu ŝi mortus tra-fike", a crime novel that is quite sexually explicit (even includes warnings).  Not sure if it qualifies as porn in the way you may have in mind, as it's a book.

As for videos, much porn uses no language except for the kind that is sort of universal, so ...

Finally, I keep seeing this ad for an Esperanto naturist magazine with pictures advertised in various places.  Not exactly porn, but if you want to see naked people and read Esperanto at the same time, it may fit the bill.  Though I have not seen the actual publication.

Comment: The Spanish film "diet of sex" had subtitles in Esperanto.http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/6128375/diet-of-sex-eo